# Why a div with a small height (4px) cannot fit an element？The child element is displayed outside

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, less

I checked that it wasn't the width, I set the child element to be 10% wide and only one element

```css
.pct-bar {
  height: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(121, 121,121,.3);

  .gogo {
display: inline-block;
// float: left; // If I set float, this problem will not occur
width: 10%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pct-bar">
  <span class="gogo"></span>
</div>
```

Gif: [image: problem]

The only way I've found so far is to set float to the child or display:flex to the parent, but hopefully that will answer the question.
The text is translated by translator, if you have any questions, please feel free to ask, thank you

Comment: I don't understand the problem, can you please create a runnable snippet in your post that demonstrates it?

Comment: You code seems to be missing multiple things. Please [edit] to add more details and make de [mre]

Comment: Up voted because this was actually an interesting css puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

For `inline-block` element there's line height in the play. Effectively your `.gogo` element lies on the baseline of the `.pct-bar` container (which has some default `line-height`). You can fix your issue by adding `vertical-align: top;` to the `.gogo` element.

```css
.pct-bar {
  height: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(121, 121,121,.3);
}
.gogo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="pct-bar">
  <span class="gogo"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Bravo!  I just assumed that inline-block should have made it work, but I didn't consider the line height. +1

Answer (score -2):

<strike>You could set min-height for .gogo</strike>

```
.gogo {
    ...
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

sorry, got you wrong.

maybe display: table; might be an option?